# Moda sin NAS con dato al azar

Tags: r

¿Cómo hago para sacar la moda sin contar los NAS, y que cuando haya empate coja un dato al azar?

Por ejemplo

```
datos2<-data.frame(
  col1=c("AAA","BBB","AAA","BBB","BBB","AAA","BBB","BBB"),
  col2=c(1060,8400,2060,9750,1,2,3,3),
  col3=c(200,800,200,NA,NA,30,NA,600)
)
```

```
moda <- function(x, useNA = "no") {
  xtabla <- table(x, useNA = useNA)             
  names(xtabla[xtabla == max(xtabla)])}
```

Quiero sacar la moda de la col3 según la col1

```
datos2 %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  mutate(col4 = moda(col3))
```

Da error por los empates.
Por lo que en caso de empate tendría que seleccionar un número cualquiera (de los que han empatado)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema creo que los has identificado correctamente, cuando tienes dos o más modas, estás retornando todas estas, cosa que no esta mal, pero el problema es que en tu caso, al agrupar, estarías esperando un solo valor. No sé si lo correcto es ignorar valores de moda para quedarnos con uno solo, pero si este fuera el caso, puedes simplemente asegurarte de retornar siempre uno:

```
datos2 %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  mutate(col4 = moda(col3)[1])
```

Con `moda(col3)[1]` nos aseguramos de obtener la primer moda siempre, con lo que evitamos al menos el error. Otra forma, si queremos respetar los casos con más de una moda, deberíamos guardar una lista:

```
datos2 %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  mutate(col4 = list(moda(col3)))
```

Ahora, si quieres que la función retorne un moda al azar, simplemente agrega un `sample` sobre las modas:

```
moda <- function(x, useNA = "no") {
  xtabla <- table(x, useNA = useNA)             
  sample(names(xtabla[xtabla == max(xtabla)]),1)
}
```

Por último te recomiendo esta función ([ver](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_mean_median_mode.htm))

```
getmode <- function(v) {
   uniqv <- unique(v)
   uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

que tiene la ventaja que retorna el mismo tipo de valor recibido.